# Odoo 17 Enterprise Project Planning and Timesheet

Tags: project, odoo-17

We have an Odoo 17 Enterprise. We have Project Planning where we are adding resource planning hours and allocated percentage.

Both these allocated hours and percentages we need to display on the Project Timesheet grid view with employee and project wise. We are facinc challanges to get employee id.

Please reply to me with the approach or solution how to resolve it.

We have identified the files and place but not getting employee id. So I need employee and project id to display it.